# Куда установить локальный пакет?

Tags: lua

Например, у меня есть некий скрипт `some_script.lua`.

Как и куда я могу его установить, чтобы потом можно было подключать в любом скрипте (писать `require "some_script"`)?

Я посмотрел в сторону *LuaRocks*, но так и не нашел решение. Я увидел только то. что можно создавать публичные пакеты.

Answer (score 2):

поместите скрипт в любое из мест, перечисленных в переменной [`package.path`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.path). именно её содержимое анализируется при поиске пакетов функцией `require`.

посмотреть содержимое этой переменной можно, например, так:

```
$ lua -e 'print (package.path)'
```

или в интерактивном режиме:

```
$ lua
> =package.path
```

пути в этой строке по умолчанию отделяются символом <kbd>;</kbd>, но в разных операционных системах для этого могут служить разные символы. уточните из содержимого переменной [`package.config`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.config).